# Django DateTime not storing ISO 8601 with T/Z (letters), but spaces instead

Tags: django, datetime

So right now, my model is declared with serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=["iso-8601"]) and the value I get when printing is:

2020-10-03 11:15:00+00:00

Ideally that'd be 
2020-10-03T11:15:00+00:00

or even more ideally, if it doesn't require a ton of work,
2020-10:03T11:15:00Z

How do I accomplish this? Or when its sent over the network/to front-end, does this happen automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're talking about serializing or deserializing here.

Comment: Serializing I think? I'd like to make it so when sending back data from the Model w/ DateTime Fields it is sent back formatted as I mentioned. As I understand it, serializing means going from model instance -> disk/network and deserializing means disk/network -> model instance. So in this case, send it out as mentioned format-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting the default string evaluation of a datetime function here. What you want to do when printing is override the default string function.  In your serializer, you want to pass a `format` argument [(look here)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield), and construct the string using a combination of the python date formats [(date formats)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). This formatting makes python date strings fully customizable.

For you, your string should look something like... `%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%SZ`

Comment: Using format='iso-8601' gets me the same output when I go in and print the responses in my unit tests. I've also specified input_format='iso-8601', but that's for deserializing I believe

Comment: yeah so deserializing is input format.  If you define the actual string yourself, you will be able to put the T in there and remove the milliseconds.  It won't be as simple as putting in 'iso-8601,' but it will give you exactly what you need. I've updated the answer with the format that you are probably looking for.